# MySQL. Insert and select data to database without duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, duplicates

I'm creating flash game, where players need to pass game as quickly as they can. I have made players TOP 10 and it's ordered by time(from lowest to highest), but I have a problem, if the same player play few times he is always adding to database. I need to make that player and his best (lowest) time only once will be written to database or only once printed out his name. (If player's Time is lower than is saved in database only in that case I need update/insert It.) Thank you.

Example how It is:

```
Peter 00:07
Peter 00:09
Peter 00:12
John 00:17
John 00:21
```

Example how should be:

```
Peter 00:07
John 00:17
```

here is my SelectFromDB.php

```
<?php 
    $time = $_POST['time'];     
    session_start();
    $name = $_SESSION['vardas']; 
    $time = strtotime($time);
    $times = date('s:H:i', $time);
    $_SESSION['test'] = $times;
    $_SESSION['test1'] = $username;


    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_db","pass","my_db");

    $query = "SELECT userName,time FROM eurokos ORDER by time ASC LIMIT 10";
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
} else {
//    printf(" ", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}
 header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    echo '<results>';
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo $row["userName"].' '.$row["time"]."\n";
        }
        $result->free();
    }
    echo '</results>';
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Here is my InsertToDB.php

```
<?php 

    $time = $_POST['time'];
    session_start();
    $name = $_SESSION['vardas']; 
    $time = strtotime($time);
    $times = date('s:H:i', $time);      
    $_SESSION['test'] = $times;
    $_SESSION['test1'] = $username;

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_db","pass","my_db");
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT into eurokos (time, userName) VALUE (?,?) ")) {
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
} else {
//    printf(" ", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}


$stmt->bind_param('ss', $times, $name);
  // $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);

   $stmt->execute();

   if ($stmt->error != '') {
       echo ' error:'.$stmt->error;
   } else {
       echo 'success';
   }
   $stmt->close();
} else {
   echo 'error:'.$mysqli->error;
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: You only need to change your select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only change your select:

```
SELECT userName,min(time) time FROM eurokos group by userName order by time ASC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, if I use     `$query = "SELECT userName,min(time) FROM eurokos group by userName order by time ASC LIMIT 10";` it returns names without time

Comment: I updated the answer, it may be because you only use the field `time`, so select the field you want and change its name. Use the updated answer.

Comment: let me tell you that this is a temporary solution, you need to change how you store your data, because this table is becoming extremely big with the `userName` repeated too much. Maybe it is time to better configure your database or better, change it to a horizontal design, with mongodb, hadoop, etc.

Comment: Maybe here is better solution to change INSERT as @chandresh_cool said. Just I can't complete it sucessful.

Comment: Let me tell you that a horizontal database could be great for this model, but if you want to continue with relational databases, it is better if you could use a `View`, to always have the `top 10` solution, without having to query your HUGE eurokos table.

Answer (score 0):

Do this before inserting record

1. Run a select query and see if that username exist.
2. If it exists, compare the two time if the db time is greater than the
   value to be inserted, run an update query to update the time to the
   new value.
3. If it does not exist run insert query for that user.

Comment: Thank you for answer. How the if function must look like for checking if It exist on database?

Comment: just do this if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) then records exist or not exist

Comment: Thank you. Could you show me how It must look like, because I can't do It correct...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i would have done it

```
$time = _SESSION[test];
$user = "john";

$res = $con->prepare("SELECT time from eurokos WHERE userName = '$user' AND time > '$time'");
$res->execute();
$allow_new_insert = $res->num_rows;

 if(!$allow_new_insert) {
  //insert magic code for updating time here
 }
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but I have 2 different files 1 for INSERT orther for SELECT.

Comment: As I see it the SELECT.php functions as a scoreboard.
the insert file should be used as an insert/update